# instance in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class, object

```
class OMG extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <h1>Whooaa!</h1>;
  }
}

class Crazy extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <OMG />;
  }
}
```

in the code the render method of crazy class returns OMG now what is OMG that is returned ?

1. Is it the upper class ?
2. or Is it the instance of OMG class ?
3. If it is the instance of the OMG class than why does it has same name as that of OMG class ?
   very much confused ????????????

Comment: It is simply a Parent Child Relationship here between the components. OMG returns you the ```<h1>Whooaa!</h1>```

Answer (score 0):

There is no "upper class"

That's just a component calling another (as a function that call another function)
You can compare that code to something like

```
function OMG() {
  console.log('Whooaa!');
}

function Crazy(){
  OMG()
}
```

Futhermore you return a component structure that could be more than one component, which make no sense to talk about "upper class"

```
class MyBigTitle extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <h1>Welcome on my website!</h1>;
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <MyBigTitle/>
        <MyBeautifulForm/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```